Unable to 'Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database' from SSMS 20.2
Hi have attempted to deploy our on-premise SQL Database to an Azure SQLDB using SQL Server Management Studion 20.2

However, I getting the following errors:
Error SQL71627: The element User: [topbs\pina] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71627: The element User: [LAP0134-NT\serveradmin] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71627: The element User: [CAPWINDS\mY_Team] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71627: The element User: [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Can someone let me know how to get around these issues? Do you think it's because of the version of the SSMS 20.2?

It is an authentication issue are you using correct authentication?

The element User: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. 
Error SQL71627: The element Login: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property IsMappedToWindowsLogin set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Azure SQL database doesn't support Windows authentication. It supports only SQL Server authentication and Microsoft Enterprise ID authentication. However, the above user is mapped to Windows authentication, which may be the reason for the error. If you want to deploy the on-premises SQL database to Azure SQL Database, delete the users which are mapped to Windows authentication as shown below:

Then try deploying again. After deployment, create  contained users  in your database to allow users to log in to your SQL Database.
Alternatively, you can use Azure Data Migration Assistant (DMA) for your migration project, which will make the process much easier. DMA assesses your database and allows you to migrate effortlessly. You can download the tool from  here. With DMA, you can uncheck any logins (SQL71627) or views not compatible with Azure SQL (SQL71561) and proceed with the migration.
For more information, you can refer to the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/689900/error-while-migrating-on-prem-sql-db-to-azure-sql
Can't Export Data-tier Application for Azure

